How to make a REST call on the System for the System (ServiceNow)
I need to set up some REST calls in a ServiceNow instance. We need to re-use some logic that we have on REST Resources so we need to make calls from the system to the system itself (internal calls).
I'm having problems with this as I need to send the request but make sure that the REST Resource works with the current session, or current user.
For example, If I'm user A, when calling the REST Calls I need to send the current user credentials through the REST Calls so when the Resource's code runs it detects it is running as user A.
I'm not able to explicitly get the user's credentials, so I need to kind of bypass the Authorization header.
I've been looking in other places and found out that sending this header "X-UserToken" might help. But so far, it doesn't work for me. I also found out that it needs to be sent along with a cookie called "JSESSIONID"
In my PDI, I've tried the below code with one of the OTTB APIs from ServiceNow:
var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
request.setEndpoint('https://dev260217.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1');
request.setHttpMethod('GET');

request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("X-UserToken", gs.getSessionToken() );
// request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=CB997BC0634A850C212C2061F8E4F382");

var response = request.execute();
gs.log(response.getBody());

But it returns a 401.

I've also tried sending the cookie:
var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
request.setEndpoint('https://dev260217.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1');
request.setHttpMethod('GET');

request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("X-UserToken", gs.getSessionToken() );
request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=CB997BC0634A850C212C2061F8E4F382");

var response = request.execute();
gs.log(response.getBody());

But when I do that, it appears the code is stuck in an infinite loop waiting for the response:

When I try the same from the REST API explorer everything works perfectly, so this tool is making the request from the system to the system and I assume there must be a way to do it from the script.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?
Any other alternatives to workaround this?
Thanks for any help on this thread!

Where are you going to be calling this from? The process I go down is to create the REST Service in the Scripted REST [sys_ws_definition] table and configure it there. Then you can create as many Methods as you like. If you are calling it client side then you have true async Promises at your convenience.
